# Android Studio change minSdk

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio i have change AndroidManifest.xml minSdk into API 12, but still got error my style minimum require is API 11, and my currenct setting API is 8.

AndroidManifext.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

My screenshot style that cause error:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle"></item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

I have tried change minSdk and then rebuild the project but still got same error.
How is this happen? what i forgot to do? or this is a bug in android studio?
Currently i use android studio **v0.3.2**

---

Following @Wenhui comments i noticed i need to upade build.gradle too.
But still i got the same error, here is my current build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
productFlavors {
    defaultFlavor {
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: What is the minSdk set in your gradle file, which is `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Wenhui i see my build.gradle file still pointing to minSdk=8, now i have change it into 12 and still got same error.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @Wenhui Oh i see, i need to clean first, then rebuild the project. now  it working. can you please move your comment to answer section so i can i accept it.

Comment: @GusDeCooL Also, don't you have to have a value for this item? <item name="android:titleTextStyle"></item>? so that you can get rid of all compiler errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the minSdk set in your gradle file, which is build.gradle file?

---

After editing build.gradle file, clean the project, then rebuild it. You can find this menu under build command

[image]